# multiple users fill a form with next button saving data in model attribute but the model attribute is changed by other user if they work at same time

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I have a form when I open it from different PC and I log in with different accounts. The model attribute looks like it only one model attribute for all user whenever I add something to that attribute it shows for all users using that from also.

I used spring MVC java, theymelaf, and HTML.

```java
@SuppressWarnings("null")
@RequestMapping(value = "/entity/a/aa/aaa/", params = "backEntityInfo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String UpdateEntityInfo(@ModelAttribute("form") BaseForm<EntityForm> baseForm, BindingResult result,
        Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ....
}
```

Comment: Let me guess the `BaseForm` is also a property in your controller? Also how are you testing this? Really with different machines and browsers or having multiple tabs open in a single browser (as the latter generally won't work with session shared state!).

Comment: Yes it is , baseForm and I tested by using different browsers ( firefox , chrome) but same user.

Comment: You have 1 instance of a controller. This instance is shared between all your users, what do you think happens when you share the internal state of that between all your users. I.e. you have one notebook, share it with all the people on a table and you find it strange that your notes get overwritten by the ones the other people make. You should give each one a seperate notebook. Or in this case don't share the state create a fresh instance for each one.

Comment: In my case the shared instance is the base Form ? Fill an object call entity with 3 forms , in each form i fill some of attributes and in the last form i send the object to the database. How i can fill the same object for all forms?! Now i use the base form , i send it to the form and returned it.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is the same class, it matters if it is the same instance!

Comment: private BaseForm<EntityInfoForm> form1;   

 @Override
 @ModelAttribute("form1")
 public BaseForm<EntityInfoForm> getForm() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if (form1 == null) {
   form1 = new BaseForm<EntityInfoForm>(new EntityInfoForm());
  }
  return form1;
 }

Comment: and that is your problem (as I already stated multiple times) you are storing state. Just remove the instance variable and return a new instance from that method. Also don't post additional code/config as comments as those are totally unreadable.